# how to compare current row with the previous row in the same table

Tags: c#, mysql

How to compare everytime, the current record with the previous record in the same table using MySQL C# in MVC3.0.

This is my table

Historytable:

```
id  | projid|     task |   name         | description     |        date  |       type
----|-------|   -----  | -------------- |------------     |       -------|    ---------
1   |   1   |    sys21 |  validation    | validating user |      1-5-12  |    created
2   |   1   |    sys21 |  bug tracking  | background bug  |     23-7-12  |    updated
    |       |          |                |     tracking    |              |
3   |   1   |    sys21 |   bug tracking |  bug reporting  |    30-8-12   |   updated
4   |   1   |    sys21 |   bugs         |  bug reporting  |   12-9-12    |  updated
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

now i want the result such that compare the record of type updated with the previous record in order to show the previous record as the previous history and record obtained by comparing with the previous record and display only the updated fields as the current history.

now depending upon the projid retrieve the history.

and my view look like the below:

```
previous history             current history
----------------             ---------------
type:                        created
name:                        validation
description:                 validating user

--------------------------------------------------------------

type:           created                         updated
name            validation                      bug tracking
description:    validating user                 background bug tracking

--------------------------------------------------------------------
type:           updated                         updated
name:           bug tracking                    bug report    
description:    background bug tracking         bug reporting

----------------------------------------------------------------
type:            updated                        updated
name:            bug tracking                   -
Description:     background bug tracking        bug reporting

------------------------------------------------------------------------
type:            updated                        updated
name:            bug tracking                   bugs
Description:     bug reporting                  -
```

I am expecting the above output, any one plz help me out from the situation,
any king of sugesions  will be accepted...

Thankyou,

Comment: You need to add more details.

Comment: Vague question gets vague answer: loop through the rows, do your business against the data of the previous row, overwrite the previous row variable with your current row, repeat.

Comment: At MySQL side or At C# application side By using System.Data.DataTable ?

Comment: This question will be closed unless you add more detail. Give us data structures, queries, errors any more detail will help.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understood you correctly but you could approach this with the following logic:

1. Get the rows that represent the history of an item and order by date descending
2. Get the first row from above as the last change
3. Get the second row from 1. as the previous to last change
4. Compare the data

Here's a potential approach for this (using Linq):

```
var history = db.History.Where(item => item.ProjId == 1)
                        .OrderByDescending(item => item.Date);
var lastChange = history.First();
var previousChange = history.Skip(1).First();
```

Now you need to send the above rows to your comparison method. If you want to highlight the changes, you can iterate through properties of the rows and compare values for same properties like this:

```
private IEnumerable<Tuple<string, object, object>> GetChangesBetweenRows(History row1, History row2)
{
    var result = new List<Tuple<string, object, object>>();
    var properties = lastChange.GetType().GetProperties(); // both rows are of the same type
    foreach(var propInfo in properties)
    {
        var obj1 = propInfo.GetValue(lastChange, null);
        var obj2 = propInfo.GetValue(previousChange, null);
        if(obj1 != obj2)
            result.Add(Tuple.Create(propInfo.Name, obj1, obj2));
    }
    return result;
}
```

**EDIT**
Given the method above, you can iterate through a collection of history rows and get differences between any of two rows in the collection:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var history = db.History.Where(item => item.ProjId == 1)
                            .OrderBy(item => item.Date)
                            .ToArray();
    for(int i=1; i<history.Length; i++)
    {
        var diff = GetChangesBetweenRows(history[i-1], history[i]);
        DisplayDifferences(diff);
    }
}

static void DisplayDifferences(IEnumerable<Tuple<string, object, object>> diff)
{
    foreach(var tuple in diff)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Property: {0}. Object1: {1}, Object2: {2}",tuple.Item1, tuple.Item2, tuple.Item3);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, for your answer, Actually this is not exactly what i need but your logic to skip(1); will be useful only to compare two records what happens if they are more than two, and also the "result" does not contain anything accept the properties, Instead of values, will you plz edit your answer.

Comment: thankyou, for editing the answer, here i am using C# mvc4.0 and i don't have methods like the above all the methods are Controller methods of return type, ActionResult,  can't display the out put at the server side my view display the result. So, it is not possible to everytime display the record after comparision. And the code cannot be split in different methods, Do you have any other way to display the result at a time, it will be helpful...

Comment: @user1568738, what do you mean by "the code cannot be split in different methods"?